# jQuery - wrapping a comma in a <span>?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery to wrap each letter in my element in a span:

```
$('.num .stat').children().andSelf().contents().each(function() {
  if(this.nodeType == 3) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, '<span class="s-$&">$&</span>'));
  }    
});
```

I will be wrapping numbers using this. The problem I'm having is that when there is a comma in my number (e.g. 23,000) the comma is not getting wrapped.

Any idea how I can get the comma's wrapped in a `<span>` also?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Comma is not in the subset of `\w`. You may use `.` in order to match all characters:

```
$this.text().replace(/(.)/g, '<span class="s-$&">$&</span>')
```

Answer (score 1):

\w doesn't include commas, try this: /([\w\,])/g